# Opening colab from github jupyter notebook converts code to markdown

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

[Example notebook](https://github.com/gordeli/NLP_EDHEC/blob/main/colab/04_Content_Analysis.ipynb):
When I open it in colab by clicking the 'Open in colab' banner or [directly](https://colab.research.google.com/github/gordeli/NLP_EDHEC/blob/main/colab/04_Content_Analysis.ipynb):
the code cells convert to markdown even though they are code cells in the original jupyter notebook. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by editing metadata of jupyter notebook, replacing **"text" by "code"** in "colab_type":

"cell_type": "code",
"execution_count": null,
"metadata": {
"colab_type": "**text**"